# Elements in a flex container are not wrapping

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When I try to insert block elements in a flex container, they all stay on the same line as if they were inline-blocks.

I would like the two first div's to be on the same line, and the last one to be on a second line. Sadly, that doesn't seem to work.

Anyone have any idea ?

```html
<div style="display: flex">
  <div style="display: inline-block">
    This is an inline block element
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-block">
    This is an inline block element
  </div>
  <div style="display: block">
    This is a block element
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you put display flex, all the children will be flex items. No matter what display you set, will be ignored. You must control the inner behavior with flexbox properties

Comment: Try reading [this article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). It's an excellent guide on how to use the new flex-box properties.

Comment: Also, [Flexbox Froggy](http://flexboxfroggy.com/) and [Flexbox Defence](http://www.flexboxdefense.com/) are two fun little games that teach you how to use the alignment related properties of flexbox.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

An initial setting of a flex container is `flex-wrap: nowrap`. This means flex items are forced to remain in a single line.

You can override the default with `flex-wrap: wrap`.

The `display` value of flex items is ignored in flex layout.

---

A flex container, which is an element with `display: flex` or `display: inline-flex`, establishes a [***flex formatting context***](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers). Although similar to a [***block formatting context***](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#block-formatting), there are differences.

One difference is that children of a flex container ignore the `display` property.

Another difference is that, in a flex container, margins don't collapse, and the `float` and `clear` properties have no effect.

A flex container also comes with several default settings. Among them:

- `justify-content: flex-start` - flex items will stack at the start of the line
- `flex-shrink: 1` - flex items are allowed to shrink and will not overflow the container
- `align-items: stretch` - flex items will expand to cover the cross-size of the container
- `flex-direction: row` - flex items will align horizontally
- `flex-wrap: nowrap` - flex items are forced to stay in a single line

Note the last two items.

Flex items will line up in a row and cannot wrap.

If you want to have two flex items on the first line, and a third item on the second line, allow the container to be multi-line with `flex-wrap: wrap`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.box {
  flex: 0 0 45%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Also, if you want flex containers to display inline, use `display: inline-flex` not `display: flex`. These are comparable to `display: inline-block` and `display: block`.

Answer (score 4):

- use `flex-wrap:wrap` in parent because by default the `flex-wrap` is `nowrap`
- use `flex-basis:50%` in child, to divide both inline-block elements in same size.

See more detailed info about flexbox on this article: [**A Complete Guide to Flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  margin: 0
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}
.flex div {
  flex: 0 50%; /*change to 1 50% to see the difference */
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>
    This is an inline block element
  </div>
  <div>
    This is an inline block element
  </div>
  <div>
    This is a block element
  </div>
</div>
```