# How to split child elements into multiple rows/lines?

Tags: html, css

As you can see below in my snippet, I have 6 child elements in one line, how can I split them into multiple lines, lets say two elements in each line?

Any idea on how to do that?

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  top: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 1900px;
  padding: 0px;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  top: 5px;
  margin: 20px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-color: #3300ff;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  width: 1900px;
  border: 5px solid green;
  border-radius: .5em;
  padding: 5px;
  align-items: center;
}

.child {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">


  <div class="child">
    <div id="slider9" class='slider row1 col1'></div>

    <div class="my_text">
      <center>
        <p>param_1</p>
        <button class="sliderStateChange">Enable</button>
        <button id="turn_off_button9">TURN OFF</button>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div id="slider10" class='slider row6 col2'></div>

    <div class="my_text">
      <center>
        <p>param_2</p>
        <button class="sliderStateChange">Enable</button>
        <button id="turn_off_button10">TURN OFF</button>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    <div id="slider11" class='slider row1 col3'></div>

    <div class="my_text">
      <center>
        <p>param_3</p>
        <button class="sliderStateChange">Enable</button>
        <button id="turn_off_button11">TURN OFF</button>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    <div id="slider10" class='slider row6 col2'></div>

    <div class="my_text">
      <center>
        <p>param_4</p>
        <button class="sliderStateChange">Enable</button>
        <button id="turn_off_button10">TURN OFF</button>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    <div id="slider10" class='slider row6 col2'></div>

    <div class="my_text">
      <center>
        <p>param_5</p>
        <button class="sliderStateChange">Enable</button>
        <button id="turn_off_button10">TURN OFF</button>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    <div id="slider10" class='slider row6 col2'></div>

    <div class="my_text">
      <center>
        <p>param_6</p>
        <button class="sliderStateChange">Enable</button>
        <button id="turn_off_button10">TURN OFF</button>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>




</div>
```

Comment: You use `display: flex` so why not add `flex-basis: 50%` to the `.child` divs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023025/elements-in-a-flex-container-are-not-wrapping

Comment: @disinfor, Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using the parameter `flex-basis` with `50%` to limit the child to occupy half the space of the `.container`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  top: 5px;
  margin: 20px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-color: #3300ff;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  width: 1900px;
  border: 5px solid green;
  border-radius: .5em;
  padding: 5px;
  align-items: center;
}

.child {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="child">
    <div id="slider9" class='slider row1 col1'></div>
    <div class="my_text">
      <center>
        <p>param_1</p>
        <button class="sliderStateChange">Enable</button>
        <button id="turn_off_button9">TURN OFF</button>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    <div id="slider10" class='slider row6 col2'></div>
    <div class="my_text">
      <center>
        <p>param_2</p>
        <button class="sliderStateChange">Enable</button>
        <button id="turn_off_button10">TURN OFF</button>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    <div id="slider11" class='slider row1 col3'></div>
    <div class="my_text">
      <center>
        <p>param_3</p>
        <button class="sliderStateChange">Enable</button>
        <button id="turn_off_button11">TURN OFF</button>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    <div id="slider10" class='slider row6 col2'></div>
    <div class="my_text">
      <center>
        <p>param_4</p>
        <button class="sliderStateChange">Enable</button>
        <button id="turn_off_button10">TURN OFF</button>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    <div id="slider10" class='slider row6 col2'></div>
    <div class="my_text">
      <center>
        <p>param_5</p>
        <button class="sliderStateChange">Enable</button>
        <button id="turn_off_button10">TURN OFF</button>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    <div id="slider10" class='slider row6 col2'></div>
    <div class="my_text">
      <center>
        <p>param_6</p>
        <button class="sliderStateChange">Enable</button>
        <button id="turn_off_button10">TURN OFF</button>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```